# Gradle Building Schema dynamically from combined flavor dimensions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-3.0, android-flavordimension

We have two different flavor dimensions like in this example and we want to dynamically generate applicationId like

> com.company.apple

instead this script will generate an applicationId of

> null.company.apple

I believe this is because the function at the bottom iterates over the full productFlavor list and not the combined list.

```
flavorDimensions "product", "license"

productFlavors.all {
    ext.scheme = null
    ext.scheme_tail = ""
    ext.kind = null
    ext.license = null
}

productFlavors {
    apple {
        dimension "product"
        kind = "apple"
        scheme = "companyapple"
    }

    orange {
        dimension "product"
        scheme = "companyorange"
        kind = "orange"
    }

    kiwi {
        dimension "product"
        scheme = "companykiwi"
        kind = "kiwi"
    }

    com {
        dimension "license"
        license = "com"
        scheme_tail = ''
    }

    eu {
        dimension "license"
        license = "eu"
        scheme_tail = "eu"
    }

    uk {
        dimension "license"
        license = "uk"
        scheme_tail = "uk"
    }

}

productFlavors.all {
    applicationId license + ".company." + kind
    ext.fileProvider = applicationId + ".fileprovider"
    manifestPlaceholders = [scheme: "$scheme$scheme_tail", fileProvider: "$fileProvider"]
    buildConfigField("String", "FILE_PROVIDER", "\"$fileProvider\"")
    buildConfigField("String", "SCHEME", "\"$scheme$scheme_tail\"")
    buildConfigField("String", "KIND", "\"$kind\"")
    buildConfigField("String", "LICENSE", "\"$license\"")
}
```

How can I iterate over the combined list to build my buildConfig fields and applicationIds?

The manifestPlaceholders are consumed like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".FruitViewerActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="${scheme}" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${fileProvider}"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />

    </provider>
```

Thanks,
Rory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that accomplishes my goals, and then improved upon it with information from [this post by David Medenjak](https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2016/11/09/build-variants.html).

Firstly use applicationId and applicationIdSuffix to build the applicationId.
Build the file provider separately for BuildConfig and for AndroidManifest.
Publish the scheme_prefix and scheme_suffix separately for the AndroidManifest and concatenate them later.
Build the scheme from it's components in the ApplicationVariant.

```
flavorDimensions "product", "license"

productFlavors.all {
    ext.scheme_prefix = null
    ext.scheme_suffix = ""
    ext.license = null
}

productFlavors {
    apple {
        applicationId = "apple.company"
        dimension "product"
        scheme_prefix = "companyapple"
        manifestPlaceholders = [scheme_prefix: "$scheme_prefix"]

        buildConfigField("String", "KIND", "\"apple\"")
    }

    orange {
        applicationId = 'orange.company'
        dimension "product"
        scheme_prefix = "companyorange"
        manifestPlaceholders = [scheme_prefix: "$scheme_prefix"]

        buildConfigField("String", "KIND", "\"orange\"")
    }

    kiwi {
        applicationId = "kiwi.company"
        dimension "product"
        scheme_prefix = "companykiwi"
        manifestPlaceholders = [scheme_prefix: "$scheme_prefix"]

        buildConfigField("String", "KIND", "\"kiwi\"")
    }

    com {
        dimension "license"
        license = "com"
        applicationIdSuffix = "$license"

        scheme_suffix = ''
        manifestPlaceholders = [scheme_suffix: "$scheme_suffix"]
    }

    eu {
        dimension "license"
        license = "eu"
        applicationIdSuffix = "$license"

        scheme_suffix = "eu"
        manifestPlaceholders = [scheme_suffix: "$scheme_suffix"]
    }

    uk {
        dimension "license"
        license = "uk"
        applicationIdSuffix = "$license"

        scheme_suffix = "uk"
        manifestPlaceholders = [scheme_suffix: "$scheme_suffix"]
    }

}

android.applicationVariants.all {
    variant ->
        ext.fileProvider = variant.applicationId + ".fileprovider"
        buildConfigField("String", "FILE_PROVIDER", "\"$fileProvider\"")

        def product = variant.productFlavors[0]
        def license = variant.productFlavors[1]
        variant.buildConfigField("String", "LICENSE", "\"${license.license}\"")
        variant.buildConfigField "String", "SCHEME", "\"${product.scheme_prefix}${license.scheme_suffix}\""
}
```

Here are the corresponding Manifest changes:

```
    <activity android:name=".FruitViewerActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="${scheme_prefix}${scheme_suffix}" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />

    </provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apple {
    dimension "product"
    kind = "apple"
    licence = "apple"
    scheme = "companyapple"
}
```

Your missing licence in you flavour so it defaults to `null`